# Why is there a deadlock with these two queries?

Tags: mysql, database

Isolation level is READ COMMITTED

The one query is looking for records where service_id is 0 ... the other is looking where service_id is NOT IN (0, ... others ... );

I'd think they would be locking different rows?

```
    ------------------------
    LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
    ------------------------
    2017-08-18 09:01:24 7f2d05641700
    *** (1) TRANSACTION:
    TRANSACTION 201694975, ACTIVE 1 sec starting index read
    mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
    LOCK WAIT 46 lock struct(s), heap size 6544, 194 row lock(s)
    MySQL thread id 33600289, OS thread handle 0x7f2d0812b700, query id 3703173090 inf-rtpctllb02-prd.rtp.netapp.com 10.60.56.150 ctl Copying to tmp table
    SELECT
                        re.*,
                        r.config_id,
                        r.reserve_all_or_nothing,
                        r.owner,
                        r.charges
                    FROM
                        `job_charge` AS re,
                        `job` AS r WHERE
                        re.job_id = r.id AND ((re.status ='dispatched') or (re.status= 'running') or (re.status= 'held') or (re.status= 'reserved')) AND  ((re.service_id ='0')) AND r.disable = 0  ORDER BY r.priority,r.id LIMIT 10000  FOR UPDATE
    *** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
    RECORD LOCKS space id 1485 page no 987 n bits 104 index `PRIMARY` of table `ctl`.`job_charge` trx table locks 2 total table locks 2  trx id 201694975 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting lock hold time 1 wait time before grant 0 
    *** (2) TRANSACTION:
    TRANSACTION 201691925, ACTIVE 185 sec fetching rows
    mysql tables in use 4, locked 2
    1164 lock struct(s), heap size 128552, 2 row lock(s)
    MySQL thread id 33599597, OS thread handle 0x7f2d05641700, query id 3703158120 inf-rtpctllb02-prd.rtp.netapp.com 10.60.56.150 ctl updating
    UPDATE
                `job_charge`
            SET
                service_id = '0'
            WHERE 
                service_id NOT IN ('0','ctl5-staging_command-launcher.674d8c96-7c76-11e7-bc6c-ee0cf095fd00','inf-mesos-slave001.ctl.gdl.englab.netapp.com:mesos-6b256982-4ef1-4a84-ba60-58245ee7406d-S63.3987fd54-ee31-4c81-add4-4be53a6ed363:80','ctl5-staging_scheduler.912d008f-7c76-11e7-bc6c-ee0cf095fd00','ctl5-production_capacity-manager.6a869ee7-7919-11e7-bc6c-ee0cf095fd00','ctl5-production_scheduler.91de7d76-7919-11e7-bc6c-ee0cf095fd00','mysql','inf-mesos-slave001.ctl.gdl.englab.netapp.com:mesos-6b256982-4ef1-4a84-ba60-58245ee7406d-S63.48fe0555-83e9-4811-bcbc-f301da498fa6:80','ctl5-production_cleaner.6a86c5fa-7919-11e7-bc6c-ee0cf095fd00','ctl5-production_command-launcher.9f97a534-8413-11e7-bc6c-ee0cf095fd00','ctl5-production_reservation-manager.7ac1771d-7a9e-11e7-bc6c-ee0cf095fd00','ctl5-s
    *** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
    RECORD LOCKS space id 1485 page no 987 n bits 104 index `PRIMARY` of table `ctl`.`job_charge` trx table locks 1 total table locks 2  trx id 201691925 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap lock hold time 13 wait time before grant 12 
    *** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
    RECORD LOCKS space id 1485 page no 1606 n bits 88 index `PRIMARY` of table `ctl`.`job_charge` trx table locks 1 total table locks 2  trx id 201691925 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting lock hold time 0 wait time before grant 0 
    *** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Both must be different rows. You can see the page no 987 and 1606 as indicated in the statement

Here Transaction 1 is

```
SELECT
                  re.*,
                  r.config_id,
                  r.reserve_all_or_nothing,
                  r.owner,
                  r.charges
              FROM
                  `job_charge` AS re,
                  `job` AS r WHERE
                  re.job_id = r.id AND ((re.status ='dispatched') or (re.status= 'running') or (re.status= 'held') or (re.status= 'reserved')) AND  ((re.service_id ='0')) AND r.disable = 0  ORDER BY r.priority,r.id LIMIT 10000  FOR UPDATE
```

Transaction 2 is

```
UPDATE
          `job_charge`
      SET
          service_id = '0'
      WHERE 
          service_id NOT IN ('0','ctl5-staging_command-launcher.674d8c96-7c76-11e7-bc6c-ee0cf095fd00','inf-mesos-slave001.ctl.gdl.englab.netapp.com:mesos-6b256982-4ef1-4a84-ba60-58245ee7406d-S63.3987fd54-ee31-4c81-add4-4be53a6ed363:80','ctl5-staging_scheduler.912d008f-7c76-11e7-bc6c-ee0cf095fd00','ctl5-production_capacity-manager.6a869ee7-7919-11e7-bc6c-ee0cf095fd00','ctl5-production_scheduler.91de7d76-7919-11e7-bc6c-ee0cf095fd00','mysql','inf-mesos-slave001.ctl.gdl.englab.netapp.com:mesos-6b256982-4ef1-4a84-ba60-58245ee7406d-S63.48fe0555-83e9-4811-bcbc-f301da498fa6:80','ctl5-production_cleaner.6a86c5fa-7919-11e7-bc6c-ee0cf095fd00','ctl5-production_command-launcher.9f97a534-8413-11e7-bc6c-ee0cf095fd00','ctl5-production_reservation-manager.7ac1771d-7a9e-11e7-bc6c-ee0cf095fd00','ctl5-s
```

From the given message, we can see that transaction 1 is waiting for an Exclusive Lock (Denoted by X lock, lock needed for WRITING some value into the table) on the table 'ctl' primary key.

But at the same time, transaction 2 came into the picture which is already **holding** an X lock on the 'ctl' table primary key (page no 987). So, as transaction 2 is already having an X lock on 'ctl', transaction 1 can't get X lock and hence it is waiting.

But transaction 2 itself is **waiting** for another X lock on 'ctl' (different row from above, page no 1606). I think this row is being **held** by transaction 1.

So, 
transaction 1 is holding a lock on a row in page no 1606 for which transaction 2 is waiting
and
transaction 2 is holding a lock on row in page no 987 for which transaction 1 is waiting

So, both are waiting for each other and hence deadlock occurred.

Comment: That makes sense.  The part I don't understand is the WHERE conditions shouldn't be locking the same row I wouldn't think?

Comment: Innodb only prints information about few of the locks which transaction is holding. Also only last statement from each transactions is displayed, while locks rows could be locked by one of previous statements. For detailed investigation, you need to look into logs and find the conflicting statements. Reference : https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/07/17/show-innodb-status-walk-through/